# Как заставить оптимизатор составить план с учетом значения переменной?

Tags: sql, sql-server, оптимизация

В процедуре с параметром @param есть запрос вида(часть запроса):

```
....
from(
  select * from table1 where @param = 1
  union all
  select * from table2 where @param = 2
  union all
  select * from table3 where @param = 3
  union all
  select * from table4 where @param = 4
  union all
  select * from table5 where @param = 5
)t
....
```

Так вот если вместо @param подставить конкретное число(4), то в плане запроса фигурирует только одна таблица(table4).
А если стоит параметр, то план запроса процедуры соответственно не может знать к какой таблице обратиться и план строится не оптимальный.
Как заставить оптимизатор составить новый план с учетом @param?

Answer (score 1):

С этим может справится хинт:
OPTION(RECOMPILE)

Надо сказать, что не всегда это полезно, так как время составления плана может превысить выигрыш от того, что план составлен с учётом значения переменных.